# Offline access to latitude and longitude from React app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to build a little React Native sample app with only one feature.So i have already created my views with 2 fields `latitude` and `longitude` and a button that when the user clicks he gets automaticaly the `latitude` and the `longitude`.All the tutorials and videos are using maps,but i don't need to have a map but only get the 2 values(lat and long) and i would like to access them offline.I'm new in React native and steel learning

Comment: Well surely the map tutorials include a part that retrieves the coordinates? Just use that part and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 1):

To offline get lat and lng, you can go through package react-native-geolocation-service
https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service